# Update iPython to version 2.0 on Mac OS

Tags: python, ipython, enthought, canopy

I have Canopy installed on my Mac OS.  As I see the version 2.0 of iPython was been released and I want to install it.

But when I am trying to install it I get the next message:

```
$ enpkg ipython

prefix: /Users/demas/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User
No update necessary, 'ipython' is up-to-date.
ipython-1.2.1-2.egg was installed on: Sun Apr  6 17:08:21 2014
```

Why my python installation can not find the new version of IPython ?

**Update:**

I have updated package using:

```
 pip install ipython --upgrade
```

but I am not sure, is it save way to upgrade packages in the Canopy distribution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most recent version of all already-installed packages (only from enpkg version 4.6 or higher):

```
$ enpkg --update-all
```

Display available updates of already-installed packages:

```
$ enpkg --whats-new
```

Try This:

```
enpkg --remove ipython
enpkg ipython
```

Comment: $ enpkg --version
enstaller version: 4.6.3

Comment: It says: $ enpkg --update-all
No new version of any installed package is available

Comment: Yep. It removed ipython-1.2.1-2.egg and install it after. May be there is not python-2.* on canopy repositories ?

Comment: Maybe you should try Anaconda than canopy.

Comment: Hmm.. 'pip install ipython --upgrade' helps me!  Is it save way to upgrade package in the canopy distribution ?

Comment: Nope, that installs ipython on the sys path not in the canopy path. try running `which python` to see what python installation is it targeting currently.

Comment: Looks correct (I set Canopy as default python): 
$ which python
/Users/demas/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

Comment: try `ipython` in command line and see if it succeeded and check the credits above. if it has canopy, then you are good to go.

Comment: No, it doesn't nave 'canopy' in the credits.  But thanks anyway!

Comment: I have created request on Canopy site and I have got the answer, that IPython 2.0 was deployed on their repositories today.

Answer (score 2):

The iPython docs recommend two methods for installing/updating iPython on a mac. enpkg and Anaconda.  I use Anaconda, currently I am running iPython 2.0 on my Macbook.  If you want to try Anaconda out, first you must install Anaconda using their gui installer, and then run the following command in your terminal:

`conda update ipython`

Comment: Is there any advantages of Anaconda over Canopy ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Canopy personally.  Anaconda is a bit of a double edged sword as it takes a lot of disk space, and installs a large number of packages to your system to help with scientific computing all at once (which is what most ipython users are interested in).  I need numpy, matplotlib, ipython, scikit-learn and many other packages to work together, so anaconda works for me.